# ANTLR Paraphrase, what does it do?

Tags: antlr, definition

Just starting to write my first lexer and i've come across this:

```
RPAREN options { paraphrase = ")"; } : ")";
```

I'd like to know what paraphrase actually does, does it mean that in this case RPAREN can also be used as simply ) in the parser?

thanks!

EDIT - just found this online

We can use  paraphrases in Rules to make error messages user-friendly

is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paraphrase` is not a valid option in ANTLR 3 or ANTLR 4. Including it would either produce a warning or error, and it would not have any impact on behavior.

Comment: thanks for the reply, my friend next to me has copied rules from somewhere online and his lexer and parser work perfectly, is it effectively bypassing it and doing nothing?

Comment: It may have been part of ANTLR 2 (which is long before I became involved in the project), or part of a fork of the project which implemented its own options independently from the main ANTLR project.

Comment: thanks alot for the replies, I'll write my code without them :)